# How to remove duplicates (more like filter based on multiple properties) with Spark RDD in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, filter, duplicates, rdd

As a policy, we do not update our documents, but we recreate with updated values. When I will process the events, I would like to keep only the updated ones, so I would like to filter items out of my RDD based on multiple values. For instance, say an item would be:

```
{
    "name": "Sample",
    "someId": "123",
    "createdAt": "2016-09-21T02:16:32+00:00"
}
```

and when it is updated:

```
{
    "name": "Sample-Updated",
    "someId": "123", # This remains the same
    "createdAt": "2016-09-21T03:16:32+00:00" # This is greater than the one of above, since the update operation is done after the document is generated
}
```

What I have been doing is:

```
items = items.toList.
      .sortBy(_.createdAt).reverse

    items = items
      .groupBy(_.someId)
      .map(_._2.head)(breakOut)
```

but this obviously converts RDD into a list; end of Spark. How do I achieve this?

**Update**

So far, I have achieved this by looking into comments, but no luck when adding into set:

```
// Is this correct? (1)
val initialSet = sc.parallelize(List[(String, Event)]())

val addToSet = (eventSet: RDD[(String, Event)],
                event: Event) => {
    // What to do here? (2)
}

// Is this correct? (3)
val mergeSets = (p1: RDD[(String, Event)],
                 p2: RDD[(String, Event)]) => p1.union(p2)

// resultSet is of type RDD[(String, RDD[(String, Event)])]. How to get it as RDD[(String, Event)]? (4)
val resultSet = initialSet.aggregateByKey(initialSet)(addToSet, mergeSets)
```

Comment: Your current code works only by luck. There's no guarantee I'm aware of that `groupBy` preserves the order you got by the `sortBy`. Instead, make an `RDD` with `someID` as the key, `aggregateByKey` to get the one with max `createdAt` (and `map` to remove the key again if needed)

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul Thanks! I am having difficulties writing the `(U, V) => U`, i.e. second argument of `aggregateByKey`. I would appreciate any help on this. And also, I basically do `(U1, U2) => U1.union(U2)` for merging partitions. Is this correct?

Comment: Post your new code, I can't guess it :) I don't know what you mean about merging partitions, I don't think it's needed.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul Updated my question :) Thanks, very much appreciated.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to keep for each id an event with the latest timestamp?

Comment: @zero323 Exactly, I only want to keep the event where `name` is `Sample-updated`, and remove the other one

Comment: `rdd.keyBy(_.someId).reduceByKey((x, y) => if (x.createdAt > y.createdAt) x else y)`?

Comment: @zero323, do'h, missed that `reduceByKey` would do it here! .

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul It should as far as I understand the problem. If you want to turn it into an answer with some explanation be my guest.

Comment: Naah, you nailed it. OP has his answer. I'm good.

Comment: @zero323 Actually, I am happy to accept it if you could just post it as an answer. @TheArchetypalPaul Though, I would really appreciate if you could point me to where I can learn how I could use `aggregateByKey` here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use `reduceByKey` here:

```scala
rdd
  .keyBy(_.someId)
  .reduceByKey((x, y) => if (x.createdAt > y.createdAt) x else y)
  .values
```

where initial `keyBy` creates `(id, object)`, `reduceByKey` selects the most recent object, and `values` drops keys.

Answer (score -1):

First use map to get a pair RDD like (data)->(name,data)
then use aggregateByKey,it will perform an aggregate operation on pairs that have same keys just like group by.