# Spark Context not Serializable?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, filter, rdd

So, I am getting the infamous `Task Not Serializable` error in Spark. Here's the related code block:

```
val labeledPoints: RDD[LabeledPoint] = events.map(event => {

    var eventsPerEntity = try {
          HBaseHelper.scan(...filter entity here...)(sc).map(newEvent =>  {

            Try(new Object(...))
          }).filter(_.isSuccess).map(_.get)
        } catch {
          case e: Exception => {
            logger.error(s"Failed to convert event ${event}." +
              s"Exception: ${e}.")
            throw e
          }
        }
    })
```

Basically what I am trying to achieve is that I am accessing `sc` which is my Spark Context object in `map`. And in runtime, I am getting `Task Not Serializable` error.

Here is a potential solution I could think of:

Query HBase without `sc`, which I can do, but in turn I will have a list. (If I try to parallelize; I have to use `sc` again). Having a list will lead me to not being able to use `reduceByKey`, which is advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39610511/how-to-remove-duplicates-more-like-filter-based-on-multiple-properties-with-sp) in my other question. So I could not succesfully achieve this one as well, as I don't know how I would achieve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39610511/how-to-remove-duplicates-more-like-filter-based-on-multiple-properties-with-sp) without `reduceByKey`. Also I would really want to use RDDs :)

So I am looking for another solution + asking whether if I am doing something wrong. Thanks in advance!

**Update**

So basically, my question have become like this:

I have an `RDD` named `events`. This is the whole HBase table. Note: Every `event` is performed by a `performerId` which is again a field in `event`, i.e. `event.performerId`.

For every `event` in `events`, I need to calculate the ratio of `event.numericColumn` to the average of `numericColumn`of the `event`s (Subset of `events`) that are performed by the same `performerId`.

I was trying to do this when mapping `events`. Within `map` I was trying to filter events according to their `performerId`.

Basically, I am trying to convert every `event` to a `LabeledPoint` and the ratio above is going to be one of my features in my Vector. i.e. For every event, I am trying to get

```
// I am trying to calculate the average, but cannot use filter, because I am in map block.

LabeledPoint(
  event.someColumn,
  Vectors.dense(
    averageAbove,
    ...
  )
)
```

I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option, if applicable, is loading the *entire* HBase table (or - all the elements that might match one of the events in `events` RDD, if you have any way of isolating them without going over the RDD) into a Dataframe, and then using **join**.

To load data from an HBase table into a Dataframe, you can use the preview [Spark-HBase Connector](http://hortonworks.com/blog/spark-hbase-dataframe-based-hbase-connector/) from Hortonworks. Then, performing the right join operation between the two dataframes should be easy.

Comment: It ended up like `val someValue = kv._2._1._1._1._1._2` after joining, but that was basically it!

Answer (score 0):

You can add the list as a new field on the event - by that getting a new RDD (event+list of entities). You can then use regular Spark commands to "explode" the list and thus get multiple event+list item records (it is easier to do this with DataFrames/DataSets than with RDDs though)

Comment: That would be a lot of duplicate entries, as the list that will be added to event are just another event performed by the same entity. Wouldn't that be?

Comment: then you could do the dedup - or maybe I don't understand what you're trying to do

Comment: Basically, for every `event`, I am trying to fetch other events done by the same entity who did the `event`, to calculate some features. So, I am trying to do this with mapping the events, and in map, I am trying to access SparkContext to query HBase to fetch other related events of the same entity.

Comment: You have one of three options - either as Tzach suggested you read all the DB and join the two data sets. either as I suggested you read from HBase without regard to spark, add that to the relevant rows and break it out with Spark mechanisms or you handle all the data from HBase outside of Spark (using "plain" scala) not a bad option as it would be distributed. Note that in option 2,3 you'd have a lot of connection to HBase (each task)

Comment: I already have the whole table loaded in events. So filtering events within event would again be a solution but then I need sc again. I am having hard time understanding what joining two datasets means? :(

Comment: I meant filtering events within map when mapping events.

Comment: if it is the same dataset it means joining it to itself based on your criteria

Comment: I have updated my question to reflect what I am trying to achieve. I would really appreciate some help on this :)

Answer (score -1):

Its simple you cant use spark context on RDD Closure so find another approach to handle this.

Comment: This is not an answer at all.

Comment: yeah but this is also not a question because when you know why task serializable error come then change ur question its all about your approach.

Comment: You are rude and not being any helpful. Thank you for your efforts though.

Comment: I am not rude at all i am just tell you its more helpful for person who answer this question if you change your question about asking how to solve this because when you ask  about task serializable error i give reason for that between sorry if you feel its rude.

Comment: @SandeepPurohit: If you can suggest "another approach" with details then you can give a detailed answer. Other wise current answer you gave could be a comment, to help Hasan. Is that okay.

Comment: @RamPrasadG yeah you are right its my mistake i didnt post it in comment.

Comment: @RamPrasadG And regarding "another approach" its like when we know why we are getting task not serializable error then i dont think even its need to mention in question When question title is about not serializable object then i think answer is also for that. And i dont think its a big issue if he dont like answer he already downgrade it may be its take it in wrong way but for that i already told him sorry.

Comment: @SandeepPurohit okay, let's move on :)